# ¿Qué hacer cuando una peer dependency requerida no está instalada?

Tags: npm

Estoy instalando el paquete de `ngx-pagination` en angular con el siguiente comando:

```
npm install ngx-pagination --save
```

Pero me aparecen los [siguientes avisos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJsRP.png):

> npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN react-bootstrap@1.0.1 requires a peer of react-dom@>=16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN react-overlay@3.1.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN react-transition-group@4.4.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

¿Qué hacer cuando sale estas advertencias al momento de instalar el ngx pagination en angular?

Comment: Hola Luis, por favor, lee [ask] y visita el [tour] donde encontrarás más información y recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas.

Comment: No creo que haya problema. Por el momento solo son warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [install-peers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peers) para buscar e instalar las dependencias requeridas.

```
npm install --save-dev --ignore-scripts install-peers
npm install
```